# Two cases of unchecked or unsafe operations with JLists and vectors

Tags: java, vector, nullpointerexception, awt, actionlistener

I have two programs that each create a different tab in an applet where the user can enter pet types in one tab, and then select and add or remove the pet types to a list in the other tab.  I thought I had managed to work out all the problems, but both are now giving me `java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.`
I can't seem to figure out why I'm receiving these errors.  Here are the two codes.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CreatePanel extends JPanel
 {
   private Vector petList; //Instantiation of variables.  To save space, multiple variables
   private JButton button1; //were instantiated at a time when possible, such as the panels.
   private SelectPanel sPanel;
   private JLabel text1, redText;
   private JTextField petInput;
   private JTextArea petsIn;
   private Panel wPanel, alertPanel, petPanel, createPanel;



 public CreatePanel(Vector petList, SelectPanel sPanel)
  {
    this.petList = petList;
    this.sPanel = sPanel;


    // orgranize components here
    // here is an example
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

    text1 = new JLabel("Enter a Pet Type"); //Creation of the visible portions of the applet
    petInput = new JTextField();
    button1 = new JButton("Create a Pet");
    petsIn = new JTextArea("No Pet");
    wPanel = new Panel(); //Panels have to be used to ensure the porper layout of the
    petPanel = new Panel();  //applet so it conforms to assignment specifications
    createPanel = new Panel();  //making for a pretty panel, but some very ugly code
    alertPanel = new Panel();
    alertPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    createPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));
    petPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));  //Each panel has its own layout, making for layouts
    wPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));  //in layouts to get everything looking correct.
    button1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener()); //adds the listener to the button

    add(wPanel);
    wPanel.add(alertPanel);
    alertPanel.add(redText);
    wPanel.add(petPanel);
    petPanel.add(text1);
    petPanel.add(petInput);
    wPanel.add(createPanel);
    createPanel.add(new JLabel());
    createPanel.add(button1);
    createPanel.add(new JLabel());  //Have to create several blank labels to get position of
    createPanel.add(new JLabel());  //the create pet button to be positioned correctly.
    createPanel.add(new JLabel());
    createPanel.add(new JLabel());
    add(petsIn);


  }

  private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
     {
         String inputPet = petInput.getText(); //Gets the user input pet
         boolean checker = false; // A boolean check type so pets can't be added repeatedly

         for (int p = 0; p < petList.size(); p++){ //Runs a check through the petList vector
             if (inputPet.equalsIgnoreCase((String) petList.get(p))){ //If a pet already exists (ignoring case) then the check is set to true
                 checker = true; //for a later if loop to inform the user.
                 break;
             }
         }


         if(inputPet.equals("")){
             redText.setText("Please enter a pet type.");
             redText.setForeground(Color.red);
         } else if (checker == true){
             redText.setText("The pet type already exists.");
             redText.setForeground(Color.red);
         } else {
             petList.add(inputPet);
             String addedPets = (String) petList.get(0);
             for(int i = 1; i < petList.size(); i++){
                 addedPets += "\n" + (String) petList.get(i);
             }
             redText.setText("Pet type added.");
             redText.setForeground(Color.red);
             petsIn.setText(addedPets);
             sPanel.updateUI();
         }
         redText.setText("");

     } //end of actionPerformed method
  } //end of ButtonListener class

} //end of CreatePanel class
```

and

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SelectPanel extends JPanel
 {
   private Vector petList, selectList;
   private Panel bPanel, nPanel;
   private JLabel sPets, aPets, nPets;
   private int numPets = 0;
   private JButton addPet, remove;
   private JList petsAvail, petTypes;
   private JScrollPane sPane, sPane2;

   public SelectPanel(Vector petList)
     {
      this.petList = petList;

      this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      bPanel = new Panel();
      nPanel = new Panel();
      nPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
      bPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

      petTypes = new JList(petList);
      petTypes.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
      sPane = new JScrollPane(petTypes);
      petList.add(0, "Available pet(s)");

      selectList = new Vector();
      petsAvail = new JList(selectList);
      petsAvail.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
      sPane2 = new JScrollPane(petsAvail);
      selectList.add(0, "Selected pet(s)");

      aPets = new JLabel("Available pet(s)");
      nPets = new JLabel("Selected pet(s)");
      nPets = new JLabel("The number of selected pets:" + numPets);
      addPet = new JButton("Add");
      remove = new JButton("Remove");

      add(petsAvail, BorderLayout.EAST);
      add(petTypes, BorderLayout.WEST);
      add(nPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      nPanel.add(nPets);
      add(bPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      bPanel.add(addPet);
      bPanel.add(remove);

      addPet.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
      remove.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());


     // orgranize components for the panel
  }

 public void updatePetList()
  {
        petTypes.updateUI();
        petsAvail.updateUI();
        //This method can refresh the appearance of the list of pets
        //by calling updateUI() method for the JList.
        //It can be called from the CreatePanel class whenever a new pet type
        //is added to the vector and the JList appearence needs to be refreshed.
  }

 private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            Object which = event.getSource();

            if(which == addPet){
                for (int p = 1; p < selectList.size(); p++){
                    boolean check = false;

                    if(selectList.contains(petTypes.getSelectedValue())){
                        check = true;
                        break;
                    } else if(check == false){
                        selectList.addElement(petTypes.getSelectedValue());
                        petsAvail.updateUI();
                        numPets++;
                    }
                }
            } else if (which == remove){
                selectList.removeElement(petsAvail.getSelectedValue());
                updatePetList();
                numPets--;
            }



            //When the added button is pushed, the selected pet
            //should be added to the right list and the number of
            //selected pets is incremented by 1.
            //When the remove button is pushed, the selected pet
            //should be removed from the right list and the number of
            //selected pets is decremented by 1.
            //
            //Be careful for the cases when no item has been selected.
        }
  } //end of ButtonListener class

} //end of SelectPanel class
```

Any insight as to the cause of these errors and what to do about them would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that warning because you're using a generic class without specifying the generic type.  It looks like your petList vector is supposed to be a vector of Strings. Your declaration of petList should look like

```
private Vector<String> petList
```

and somewhere later...

```
petList = new Vector<String>()
```

That warning is meant to help you realize that your code might not behave as expected at runtime if you starting mixing types (usually be accident) inside your vector.  You can technically add multiple types of objects into your petList vector even though you really only want strings.  There's nothing stopping you from adding integers, other classes, or even more vectors into your vector.  Sometimes this is done on purpose by a programmer, but most of the time you really only want a single type of object to be usuable in your generic class (the vector in this case).  By specifying the type of objects to put into your vector the compiler can help you catch these accidental mixing of types (such as if you tried to put an integer into your petList vector).  It's much easier to fix those kinds of problems at compile time instead of trying to figure out what went wrong at runtime.

Read here to learn more about generics in Java:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: Adding the <String> to all the vector uses (including in the 3rd file) got rid of the warnings on all the files except the select panel file

Comment: Oh gosh, I'm going to sound stupid.  I forgot to instantiate the 'redText' JLabel in the createPanel method.  That was why it wasn't running.